# SVG stroke-dashoffset animation start (again) on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, svg

I made a simple svg-stroke-animation using css and jquery. The animations starts on click. But i can't find a way to **start it again on a second click** (or third etc). I think the solution is quite simple but still nothing worked (e.g. .addClass).
This is how it should work:
1. Stroke is visible 
2. User clicks on image
3. Stroke animation starts 
4. When done: stroke keeps visible
5. User clicks again
6. Stroke animation starts again....

This is my current code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form").click(function () {

        var path1 = document.querySelector('#umriss');
        var length = path1.getTotalLength();
        
        $(path1).css("stroke-dasharray", length);
      
    
    });

});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {

    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 700px;
}

.bild{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

svg{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    
}

#umriss {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2600;
    animation: ani1 4s linear forwards;
}


@keyframes ani1 {
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Stroke</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bild">
            <svg id="form" x="0px" y="0px" width="812.959px" height="581.971px" viewBox="0 0 812.959 581.971" enable-background="new 0 0 812.959 581.971" xml:space="preserve">
                <path id="umriss" fill="#3CC243" stroke="#141412" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M137.521,128.454        C139.812,9.278,220.056,16.972,313.194,20.365c136.466,4.97,179.837,72.616,205.304,200.859
 c21.428,107.905,195.473,45.773,260.65,56.229c39.317,6.308-28.293,212.529-53.685,245.178
 c-61.222,78.716-262.76,32.434-351.007,35.777c-102.917,3.899-125.172-88.539-81.979-175.921
 c71.457-144.56-162.979-48.431-225.951-44.29C-22.9,344.077,25.05,112.387,137.521,128.454z"/>
</svg>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using JQuery only to start the animation. Everything else is done with CSS. I've added a checkbox in your HTML that controls the animation. The checkbox is visible but you may hide it (visibility:hidden or display:none).
I hope this is what you want to achieve.

```js
$(label).click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("test");
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.bild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#umriss {
  stroke-dasharray: 2333.43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2333.43;
} 
.test #umriss {  
  animation: ani1 4s linear forwards;}


[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + label #umriss {
  animation: ani2 4s linear forwards;
}


@keyframes ani1 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2333.43;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes ani2 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2333.43;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bild">
        <input type="checkbox" id="anim"/>
        <label for="anim" id="label">
            <svg id="form" x="0px" y="0px" width="200" viewBox="0 0 812.959 581.971">
                <path id="umriss" fill="#3CC243" stroke="#141412" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M137.521,128.454        C139.812,9.278,220.056,16.972,313.194,20.365c136.466,4.97,179.837,72.616,205.304,200.859
 c21.428,107.905,195.473,45.773,260.65,56.229c39.317,6.308-28.293,212.529-53.685,245.178
 c-61.222,78.716-262.76,32.434-351.007,35.777c-102.917,3.899-125.172-88.539-81.979-175.921
 c71.457-144.56-162.979-48.431-225.951-44.29C-22.9,344.077,25.05,112.387,137.521,128.454z"/>
</svg>
          </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

In CSS I've used the selector `:checked` to start one animation or another.

#### Animation without using the checkbox:

In this case I'm using the click event to add the class `.test` to bild, and I'm using the event `animationend` to remove the `.test` class. I hope it helps.

```js
bild.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  bild.classList.add("test")
})


//umriss.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd",..... );
umriss.addEventListener("animationend",()=>{
  console.log("end")
  bild.classList.remove("test");
} );
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.bild {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#umriss {
  stroke-dasharray: 2333.43;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
} 
.test #umriss {  
  animation: ani1 4s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes ani1 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2333.43;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="bild">
            <svg id="form" x="0px" y="0px" width="200" viewBox="0 0 812.959 581.971">
                <path id="umriss" fill="#3CC243" stroke="#141412" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M137.521,128.454        C139.812,9.278,220.056,16.972,313.194,20.365c136.466,4.97,179.837,72.616,205.304,200.859
 c21.428,107.905,195.473,45.773,260.65,56.229c39.317,6.308-28.293,212.529-53.685,245.178
 c-61.222,78.716-262.76,32.434-351.007,35.777c-102.917,3.899-125.172-88.539-81.979-175.921
 c71.457-144.56-162.979-48.431-225.951-44.29C-22.9,344.077,25.05,112.387,137.521,128.454z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First: Thank you for your quick answer! Can you explain to my why a checkbox is necessary? I tried to add a class to the path but the animation won't start. In your example it works pretty fine with a checkbox but i'd like to avoid this if possible. Also: is ist possible that the stroke is already visible at the beginning at that each click start the same animation (in your example the stroke changes the directions with every click (first: counterclockwise, then: clockwise))

Comment: @jessy20 : I've updated my answer. Please take a look

Comment: Thank you so much enxaneta! This is exactly I was looking for :D